# what is the relation between Python Threads and Mutex or semaphores

Tags: multithreading, mutex, semaphore, python-multithreading, raspberry-pi2

When dealing with Python or Java threads, if we lock a thread then does it mean that we are using mutex or semaphores are just about the kernel level threads.

Comment: Yes, these are kernel level threads with kernel level synchronization primitives.

Comment: So u mean thread.lock() is not using mutex?

Comment: No, I mean exactly the opposite.

Comment: what i know is that these threads(python or java) are user level threads and not kernel level, so could please elaborate a little more.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by user or kernel level threads - the meaning is ambiguous. Plus I don't know about Java. But threads in Python are implemented as a thin wrapper around pthread lib (if available in kernel).